# cakephp $this->validates multiple recode set many

Tags: validation, cakephp, dynamic-controls

I am trying to validate dynamically added controls on the form. I have a registration form where I have an option for users to add 1 to 5 education info. I am using Jquery to handle add remove fields.

HTML Code

```
<input name="data[Usereducation][0][schoolname]" id="Usereducation0Schoolname" type="text">
<input name="data[Usereducation][1][schoolname]" id="Usereducation1Schoolname" type="text">
...................
```

On submission this generates the array as..

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [schoolname] => ) [1] => Array ( [schoolname] => ) [3] => Array ( [schoolname] => )
```

My modal has following validation.

```
public $validate = array(
    'schoolname'=>array(
            'School Name'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Please enter your School Name.'
            )
        )           
    );
```

In the controller I am trying to validate these with `$this->Usereducation->validates();`

But nothing happens. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Are you setting the data to model before validating?, can you pls put your controller code ?

Comment: Yes I did that $this->Userinformation->set($this->data);

Comment: even if you set the `data` should be `array(
 'Userinformation' => array(
  'schoolname' => 'value'
 ))` not the way you're setting there.

Comment: I am trying to validate notEmpty. So when I submit with empty fields, it is not validating.

Comment: Have you tried my code, and set the data as like I've done in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

**Use saveMany For validating the multiple records at once**

In your controller just use `saveMany/saveAll` method of model instead of `validates`, since you're having too many records to validated.

```
if ($this->UserInformation->saveMany($this->request->data)) {
    // do your stuff
} else {
    // check the validation errors here.
    pr($this->UserInformation->validationErrors);exit;
}
```

and your `$this->request->data` should be like this

```
Array(
    'Userinformation' => array(
        0 => array(
            'schoolname' => 'school 0'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'schoolname' => 'school 1'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'schoolname' => 'school 2'
        ),
    )
)
```

**Method 2:**

Here is an another way of validating multiple records at once:

*If you want to validate the records, and don't want to perform save operation it is useful..*

```
$this->ModelName->validateMany($data['ModelName']);
```

Here `$data` should look like as below

```
$data = array(
    'ModelName' => array(
        'field1' => 'value1'
        'field2' => 'value2'
        'field3' => 'value3'
    )
);
```

And you can access the validation errors (on unsuccessful validation) Using `$this->ModelName->validationErrors`

In Your case

```
if ($this->UserInformation->validateMany($this->request->data['Userinformation'])) {
    // do your stuff
} else {
    // check the validation errors here.
    pr($this->UserInformation->validationErrors);exit;
}
```

and your `$this->request->data` should be like this

```
Array(
    'Userinformation' => array(
        0 => array(
            'schoolname' => 'school 0'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'schoolname' => 'school 1'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'schoolname' => 'school 2'
        ),
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you please help me out with this one as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999401/hasandbelongstomany-friends-model-cakephp Thanks in advance.